# What could be the solution for automatically Document Image Unwarping caused by 3d warping?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to make some kind of python script that can do that.

#### In my case i just want very simple unwarping as follow

1. Always having similar backgroud
2. Always Placing page at similar position
3. Always having same type of wraped image
   [image: ApplicationFrameHost_OBhqMlLofR]

### I tried following methods but didn't work out.

- I tried so many scanning apps but no app can unwarp 3d wrap
  for example this one [microsoft office lens](https://www.bralin.com/microsoft-office-lens-how-to-article)
  [image].
- I tried [page_dewarp.py](https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp). But it does not work with pages having spaces between texts or having segments of texts and most of times for that kind of images it just revert cure from left to right or vice versa and also unable to detect actual text area for example
  [image: output of page_dewarp.py]
- I found [deep-learning-for-document-dewarping](https://github.com/thomasjhuang/deep-learning-for-document-dewarping) that is trying to solve this problem by using [pix2pixHD](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD) But i am not sure this is gona work and this project don't have trained models and currectly not solving the problem. should i train a model with just following training data `train_A` - warped input images and `train_B` - unwarped output images as mentioned at [pix2pixHD](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD). I can generate training data by make warped and uwarped images using blender 3d. In this way i can generate so many images by using some scanned book's pages by just rendering uwarped image and warped image it like someone taking photos of pages but virtually.

Comment: The deep learning approach will be a good experiment.  Be prepared to try many augmentation techniques for  your images, as the models can be surprisingly sensitive to  small differences between your blender warps and real warps.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply.
I will try to train a model.

Comment: Don't be discouraged, and try all of the different augmentations you can think of - including contrast, blur, noise, and other distortions likely to have been caused during the original scanning of the image.  If your model is overfitting increase the type and severity of the augmentations.  Eventually you may find a good combination.

Comment: Yes, i can create a python script in blender for generating different-different versions of same page with lost of different-different augmentations or variety of wraps.

I am doing AI training for the first time thats why i am so confused.

Comment: Good luck, and fast.ai is a good platform for this type of project.

Comment: I posted this queston like 4-5 times Someone from `ocr` tag was downvoting this question again and again just discouraging to do this so i just deleted that tag, and added new tags(like deep-learning), now that question reached to you(encouraging person) Thanku.

Comment: It's probably extremely difficult and may only end up giving you mediocre results, which is why they may be cynical.  None the less you will learn something by trying so don't let people discourage you and who knows you might stumble onto an effective solution.

Comment: Thanku so much for that.

Comment: @NavpreetDevpuri did you try the deep learning approach with the train_A train_B data provided? did it work?

Comment: @rishabh-vij i did not tried it yet.

Comment: Found [that](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cvl/content/papers/2019/SagnikKe_ICCV19.pdf) seems related.